# Is there an IE11 compatible workaround to get Vue to render multiple table rows per item in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vue.js, internet-explorer-11

I would like to render multiple table rows per item in a v-for loop without wrapping the elements in another element e.g. `<tbody>`.

For example

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <!-- v-for="item in items" -->
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    <!-- /v-for -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have got this working in Chrome using `<template>` as the root element, as below, however this approach does not work in Internet Explorer 11.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <template v-for="item in items">
      <tr></tr>
      <tr></tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a more detailed example here
https://plnkr.co/edit/wfsFvbifAwq7ycZv?p=info

I'm looking for a way to achieve the same result but in a way that works with IE11.

Vue JS templates need to have a single root element and the recommended way seems to be wrapping the table rows in a `<tbody>` but in my case the rows are already in a tbody and nested tbodys are not allowed.

I'm aware the UX in my example isn't great but I can't change it easily so I'm not after suggestions of changing the page layout unless there are no other options.

Comment: Can you place your first <tr> in a <thead> element so that you can reserve <tbody> entirely for your `v-for` <tr>s?

Comment: Unfortunately not as in my use case there is one thead and multiple tbodys in the table. Plus the first row is different per tbody

Answer (score 1):

Answered by Linus Borg over at the Vue Forums

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-there-an-ie11-compatible-workaround-to-get-vue-to-render-multiple-table-rows-per-item-in-a-for-loop/61814/2

The  approach does not work in IE if the template element is defined directly in the HTML page.

It works if I use a string template or an element to wrap the template, i.e.:

```
<script type="x-template" id="table-template">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="item in items">
       <!-- ... -->
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
new Vue({
   //...
  template: '#table-template'
})
```

Thanks Linus <3